# UIImageView Image is Not Being Set

Tags: ios, uiimageview, uiimage

I have a TableView that contains a list of names for the cell text taken from an NSArray called arryData. In the didSelectRowAtIndexPath, I have:

```
NextViewController *nextController = [[NextViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"NextViewController" bundle:nil];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:nextController animated:YES];
    [nextController changeProductText:[arryData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
```

In the NextViewController I have:

```
- (IBAction) changeProductText:(NSString *)str{
    NSLog(@"whosthere%@", str);
    self.title = str;
    if ( [str isEqualToString: @"Row 1 Name"]) {
        lblProductTxt.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"row1name.png"];
        job.text = @"Sr. Minister & Elder";
        NSLog(@"Row 1 Name");
        emailaddress = @"Row1Email@att.net";
           } 
...
}
```

When I click on the Row 1 name, my console shows "whosthererow1name" and the other NSLog fires off Row 1 Name, however the image doesn't show up, and neither does the text. I have this built using IB and XIB file.  I made sure that the Class matched up and that the IBOutlet for both the UILabel and UIImageView were connected.  They were.

Why would this not be working?

UPDATE:
Just tested this on a 6.1 device and 7.0 device.  6.1 it works fine, 7.0 it shows no image.

Comment: maybe a dumb question, but are you sure that your image is png format?

Comment: try to remove .png and check it

Comment: It is definitely PNG format. Just ran it on iOS 6.1.  6.1 it works fine, 7.0 it shows no image.

Comment: well it's really strange behaviour. Can you share your project? So we could help you

Answer (score 1):

The reason this doesn't work is because the label and the image view will be null at the time you call changeProductText: since nextController's view hasn't been loaded yet. What I don't understand is why it worked in iOS 6. Are you sure you did it exactly this way in iOS 6? The way to do this is to pass a string (and anything else you want) to a property you create in nextController, and populate the UI elements in viewDidLoad.

Comment: Positive it works on iOS 6.  Have one device on 7 and one on 6, run them both on debug from Xcode and iOS 6 works.

Comment: Per the suggestion, I set an NSString property on the nextController, and set the indexPath.row name as that property on selection of row.  Then I changed code to be a viewWillAppear instead of just a method with the string, and it all works now.

Answer (score 0):

Is the UIImageView actually initialized and on the screen somewhere? Does the image file actually exist? Make sure that both the UIImageView and the UIImage you are creating are not nil by setting a breakpoint at the point of assignment in the code.

Comment: They both exist.  On viewDidLoad of the controller I run ` CALayer * l = [lblProductTxt layer];
   
    
    [l setMasksToBounds:YES];
    [l setCornerRadius:11];
    [l setBorderWidth:2.0];
    [l setBorderColor:[[UIColor blackColor] CGColor]];
` to give a rounded frame around the image.  The frame shows, but no image.  I can set an image manually in IB and it will show.  I also checked file inspector on image to make sure that it was indeed added to the Target.

Comment: Just ran it on iOS 6.1.  6.1 it works fine, 7.0 it shows no image.